# jxbrowser 7 altenative method for JSObject.toJSONString()

Tags: java, jxbrowser

I have a java application which developed by using JxBrowser 6.21. And wiling to migrate to JxBrowser 7. There was a **toJSONString()** method in **JSObject** class in JxBrowser version 6. But JxBrowser 7.2 version there is no method **JsObject.toJSONString()**. Is there a alternative way to do this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com it has mentioned that JSON support will be implemented in there next release. Hope your problem will be solved in JxBrowser next release.

> [In Next Release](https://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/roadmap/#in-next-release)
>   JSON
>   Provide functionality that allows creating JavaScript objects from a JSON string and convert existing JavaScript objects to a JSON string.